# Conditional Formatting formula for large amounts of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wondering how do you create conditional formatting so that for when any of my monthly stock on hand levels falls below the min which is listed in column L, 
 it turns the font blue.

I'm just a little confused as each row has its own min, and not sure about how to use the formula to determine which cell to format on excel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these steps:**

- Select first row B2:K2.
- Go to Conditional Formatting.
- Highlight first option 'Highlight Cells Rule' & Select 'Less than' from right 
  pop up menu.
- In 'Format Cell That Are Less Than', select cell Cell L2.
- Will looks like $L$2, modify it to $L2.
- For 'With' in same dialogue, click list box & select 'Custom Format'.
- Apply the Format of your choice.
- Finish with OK.
- Select B2:K2, select Format Painter ICON & apply it to entire Range.

*Check the Screen Shot below:*

[image]

**NB:** Purposely I've modified values for Jul & Sep in row 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Do this row by row (and you can copy the formula). That way you are asking the formula to find any number on that row equal or less than (or maybe just less than) the number in Min and turn those cells blue.

Just highlight the cells B2-K2, click Conditional Formatting under Styles, then Highlight Cell Rules - More Rules and fill out the fields in the dialog box then click OK. After you can copy that to your other B-K rows.